# C++ Segmentation fault error when storing integers as int arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm having a segmentation fault error, and I'm not sure why:
I have this code:
entierlong.h

```cpp
const int MAXCHIFFRES = 1000;

typedef int tabEnt[MAXCHIFFRES];

struct EntierLong
{
    bool Negatif;
    tabEnt Chiffres;
};
```

```cpp
EntierLong addition(EntierLong n1, EntierLong n2)
{
  int retenue,somme,i;
  n3 = Convertir(0);
  if (n1.Negatif != n2.Negatif)
  {
    cout<<"Les entierslongs doivent être de même signe.\n";
    return(n3);
  }
  n3.Negatif = n1.Negatif;
  retenue = 0;
  for(i=0;i<=MAXCHIFFRES-1;i++)
  {
    somme = n1.Chiffres[i]+n2.Chiffres[i]+retenue;
    retenue = int(somme>=10);
    n3.Chiffres[i]=somme-retenue*10;
  }
  return(n3);
}

EntierLong Un_2=Convertir(0), Un_1=Convertir(1), Un=Convertir(0);
EntierLong fibonnaci(int n)
{
    int i=0;
    switch(n)
    {
        case 0:
            return(Un_2);
            break;
        case 1:
            return(Un_1);
            break;
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        Un=addition(Un_2,Un_1);
        Un_2 = Un_1;
        Un_1 = Un;
    }
    return(Un);
}
```

Basically I'm storing integer in an array of integer to compute large fibonnaci numbers
everything works fine until I increase `MAXCHIFFRES` above 1000
It gives me `Segmentation fault: 11`
As I understand it, my heap is overflowed at some point
I've tried putting the definitions outside the functions to remove this problem to no avail.

What I don't understand is that summing two `EntierLong` togethers works with my function.
I'm very new to cpp, so please let me know if my question is asked improperly
Thanks in advance

Comment: n3 is not defined

Comment: You probably allocate too much memory on the stack.

Comment: This was the problem @Zaiborg, another function called an array of arrays.
I solved it by using a `static` definition.

Comment: You should definitively have a look at c++ standard containers (see my answer) for allocation. C++ without container is not really a leap from "good old C". Allocating on the heap is ok as long you do not need too much memory.

Comment: The problem I have with your solution is that the struct was given to me during the assignement and I was not allowed to change it.
I'd definetly do it your way outside of school however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have memory allocation issues you can replace your `EntierLong` type by

```
struct EntierLong
{
    bool Negatif;
    std::vector<int> Chiffres;
    EntierLong()
    {
        Chiffres.resize(MAXCHIFFRES,0);
    }
};
```

The constructor will allocate `Chiffres` array on the heap.